# Java Process Builder redirect output works in Eclipse, not as jar

Tags: java, process, stdout, processbuilder

I'm using the process builder to launch new main classes. I do `builder.inheritIO();` and it works in Eclipse (stdout and stderr redirect to the single console). However, when I export a jar, the the output doesn't redirect (only original process output showing). I'm on Java 7. Any ideas where I should look at?

Some code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(arr);
//builder.redirectOutput();
//builder.redirectError();
//builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
// those don't work either
builder.inheritIO();
Process p = builder.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in java under windows. Will be fixed in java8.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8023130 .

You can use the old way and redirect the streams manual.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("...");


Process p = builder.start();

p.getOutputStream();
p.getInputStream();
p.getInputStream();
```